# print all layers output

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

Given the following model, how to print all layers values ?

```js
const input = tf.input({shape: [5]});
    const denseLayer1 = tf.layers.dense({units: 10, activation: 'relu'});
    const denseLayer2 = tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'});
    const output = denseLayer2.apply(denseLayer1.apply(input));
    const model = tf.model({inputs: input, outputs: output});
    model.predict(tf.ones([2, 5])).print();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print layers, one needs to define the layers to output in the model configuration, using, `outputs` property. Using destructuring assignement on `model.predict()` one could retrieve the intermediate layers to output

```js
const input = tf.input({shape: [5]});
        const denseLayer1 = tf.layers.dense({units: 10, activation: 'relu'});
        const denseLayer2 = tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'});
        const output1 = denseLayer1.apply(input);
        const output2 = denseLayer2.apply(output1);
        const model = tf.model({inputs: input, outputs: [output1, output2]});
        const [firstLayer, secondLayer] = model.predict(tf.ones([2, 5]));
        firstLayer.print();
        secondLayer.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like

```
    for(var i = 0; i < tf.layers.length; i++)
      model.predict(tf.layers[i].value).print();
      // OR
      model.predict(tf.layers[i].inputs).print();
```

I don't know how is the structure of your array, but something like that could work.

Comment: your tf.layers is not an array. You can have a look at the documentation https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#class:layers.Layer. Anyway, your code is throwing errors