# Weights and predictions of each layer

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow.js

I am trying to create a simple neural network viewer like the diagram below.  I can get the trained weights, but where are node values stored in a tensorflow *js* layer when prediction has run?  In other words, I can get the line values, but not the circled values.  In a simple network these are as simple as the x and y passed into the fit method.

[image]

Comment: I think that this should answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483285/print-all-layers-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getWeigths](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.layers.Layer.getWeights) allows to retrieve the weights of a layer

Using `tf.model`, one can output the prediction of each layer

```js
const input = tf.input({shape: [5]});
        const denseLayer1 = tf.layers.dense({units: 10, activation: 'relu'});
        const denseLayer2 = tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'});
        const output1 = denseLayer1.apply(input);
        const output2 = denseLayer2.apply(output1);
        const model = tf.model({inputs: input, outputs: [output1, output2]});
        const [firstLayer, secondLayer] = model.predict(tf.ones([2, 5]));
        
        console.log(denseLayer1.getWeights().length) // 2  W and B for a dense layer
        denseLayer1.getWeights()[1].print()
        console.log(denseLayer2.getWeights().length) // also 2
        // output of each layer WX + B
        firstLayer.print();
        secondLayer.print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

One can also do the same thing using `tf.sequential()`

```js
const model = tf.sequential();

// first layer
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, inputShape: [4]}));
// second layer
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1}));

// get all the layers of the model
const layers = model.layers
layers[0].getWeights()[0].print()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

However with `tf.sequential`, one cannot get the prediction of each layer as the way one can with `tf.model` using the `output` passed as parameter in the config of the model

Comment: Interesting.  So the apply method seems to be what maps layers to each other when not using tf.sequential.  Is there an option to get the values out from layers in a ts.sequential instead of tf.model, since tf.sequential already maps the layers to each other in the order they are added?  Make sense?