# TensorFlowJs | How To Get Model Delta Between Two Trained Models

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have (2) identical models:

- Model1 = trained on base dataset
- Model2 = trained on base dataset + additional dataset

How do I get a delta between Model1 and Model2 with TensorFlowJs?

```
const Model1 = tf.sequential();
Model1.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 50, inputShape: [1], activation: 'relu', kernel_regularizer: 'l2'}));
Model1.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1], activation: 'sigmoid'}));
Model1.compile({loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', optimizer: 'rmsprop', metrics: 'accuracy'}); 

const Model2 = tf.sequential();
Model2.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 50, inputShape: [1], activation: 'relu', kernel_regularizer: 'l2'}));
Model2.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1], activation: 'sigmoid'}));
Model2.compile({loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', optimizer: 'rmsprop', metrics: 'accuracy'}); 

# train/fit Model1 with base dataset
# train/fit Model2 with base dataset + additional dataset
# get difference between Model1 and Model2 with TensorFlowJs here
```

I expect to get the weights difference between Model1 and Model2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the weights of a model, one can use [getWeights](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.layers.Layer.getWeights) for each layer. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54293937/weights-and-predictions-of-each-layer/54297273#54297273) describe how to do just that.

After retrieving the weights of the two models, one can find the difference between the two by using the [sub](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#sub) operator.

Comment: awesome thanks! I now have the weights delta:) Next question is how do I add the weights to Model1? Getting this error "errors.ts:48 Uncaught (in promise) Error: You called setWeights(weights) on layer "sequential_3_model" with a weight list of length 1, but the layer was expecting 4 weights."