# Removing (Pruning) neurons from TensorFlow.JS layer

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow.js

I'm new to Tensorflow, Neural Nets and I never used other than the JavaScript version of Tensorflow. And basically I'm experimenting and studdying all this.

Reading the (Python) Tensorflow docs I saw that Pruning can be done by TF.CONTRIB.MODEL_PRUNING, but, as far as I have found, there is nothing similar for Tensorflow.JS. So I'd like to experiment a bit and implement at least a very simple / basic pruning method.

This "very simple / basic pruning method" can be something like removing from the hidden layers those neurons whose weight is very near to 0. I would then train the model a bit more and see if I can recover the loss in accuracy.

I know I can access the weights with something like this:

```
const weights = model.layers.map(layer => {
  return layer.getWeights()[0].dataSync();
});
```

What I would like to know if it is actually possible to find and remove units associated with those weights (and if I can do this during training).

Thanks!

Edu

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the weights on the model. The same way you retrieve the model weights using `get`, you can use `set` to change the weights of your model.

```
model.fit(x, y, {epochs: 1000, 
      callbacks: {
      onEpochEnd: () => {
        // check your weight
         model.layers[0].getWeights()
        // set your weiths
         model.layers[0].setWeights([tensors])
      }
    }})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So if I cannot REMOVE the neurons I may be able to iterate the weights, collect the ones of interest, create a new model and set the weight values of those collected... yep that could work!

Comment: @EduardoG.R. you can retrieve the layers of your model and build another model from it. Here is how to build a new model from the layers of an initial model: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51483897/get-the-layers-from-one-model-and-assign-it-to-another-model

Comment: That's useful, thanks @edkeveked . I will come up with some "pseudo-pruning" code and share the experience.

Comment: @EduardoG.R. Maybe you can mark this answer as accepted and open a new thread with the new code :)

Comment: I'm still searching if neurons can be removed, if at the end of the day I find nothing else I will!